# ionic4 angular route history

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm using Ionic4 and navigating with the ionic angular router.

Is there a way to access the ionic navigation stack history?

I want to check if the url that is accessed was routed directly or through the application.

Answer (score 0):

Ah solved it using IonRouterOutlet.canGoBack()